# Text thrown out of div's boundaries in wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, elementor

The goal I wanted to achieve was creating offer container by hand to list full description with price of some item on a wordpress page.

I decided to write my own script which displays "show more" button when text exceeds some length and afterwards, while it's clicked on an item rolls down itself so it makes all sentences visible.

Nonetheless, I noticed some snag on scaling to mobile view cause container threw out content outside, even though content has got property set as overflow: hidden so it should be fixed to container anytime I think.

Got some observations on casual html file with the same mechanics written by me and the behaviour is totally normal contrary to wordpress elementor page creator.

Here I post some code with the screenshots along.

[CODE SNIPPET](https://jsfiddle.net/vlonewulf/nkhbL4m7/52/)

```js
   /* Checking if read more button is needed */
        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', countLines, false);

        function countLines() {
            var offers = document.getElementsByClassName('offer-text');

            for (var i = 0; i < offers.length; i++) {
                displayOrNotButton(i);
            }

            function displayOrNotButton(i) {

                var showMoreContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('show-more-container')[i];

                if (offers[i].offsetHeight < offers[i].scrollHeight) {
                    // your element has an overflow
                    // show read more button
                    return;
                } else {
                    // your element doesn't have overflow
                    showMoreContainer.style.display = "none";

                }
            }
        }
        /* End of checking out */

        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

            /* It's for rolling down items and backwards*/
            var showMoreContainers = document.getElementsByClassName("show-more-container");
            var offerContainers = document.getElementsByClassName("offer-container");
            var checkboxes = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < showMoreContainers.length; i++) {

                (function (i) {

                    checkboxes[i] = showMoreContainers[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
                    checkboxes[i].addEventListener('change', e => {
                        showOrHideText(e.target.checked, i);
                    })
                })(i);
            }

            function showOrHideText(checked, i) {

                                if (checked) {
                    offerContainers[i].style["max-height"] = "none";
                } else {
                    offerContainers[i].style["max-height"] = "450px";
                }
            }
        })
        /* End of rolling mechanics */
```

```css
:root {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#all-offers-section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  justify-items: center;
  gap: 5em;
}

.offer-container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 300px;
  max-height: 450px;
  padding: 2em 2em 100px 2em;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.offer-text {
  margin: 10px;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.offer-price-tag {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* reserved for show more button */
.show-more-container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 4.5em;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
}

#all-offers-section label {
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.125em;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

div.show-more-container > input {
  display: none;
}

label:after {
  content: "Show more";
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
  content: "Show less";
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  #all-offers-section {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}

/* end of show more button styling */
```

```html
    <div id="all-offers-section">
        <div class="offer-container">
            <h2 class="offer-title">
                BRONZE
            </h2>
            <hr>
            <div class="offer-text">
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam luctus velit libero, sit amet
                    porttitor turpis gravida ut. Integer tempus auctor imperdiet. Sed varius sit amet purus sed luctus.
                    Maecenas scelerisque magna felis, vel ultrices enim sagittis eu.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="show-more-container">
                <input id="ch-1" type="checkbox">
                <label id=label-show-1 for="ch-1"></label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span class="offer-price-tag">
                    100
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="offer-container">
            <h2 class="offer-title">
                VIP
            </h2>
            <hr>
            <div class="offer-text">
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam luctus velit libero, sit amet
                    porttitor turpis gravida ut. Integer tempus auctor imperdiet. Sed varius sit amet purus sed luctus.
                    Maecenas scelerisque magna felis, vel ultrices enim sagittis eu. Phasellus at sapien sit amet diam
                    pulvinar ornare quis tempus ex. Phasellus cursus eros ac urna blandit, ac tincidunt mi bibendum.
                    Aliquam tempus ligula eu orci lacinia, quis feugiat purus luctus. Aenean eu ex dolor. Aliquam
                    bibendum eu lectus in placerat. Nulla commodo fermentum felis ac pharetra. Aliquam ut ligula eu urna
                    lacinia lacinia sed vitae elit. Mauris sed dui et turpis hendrerit maximus a in diam.

                    Fusce eget finibus velit. Nunc condimentum sed mauris sed ultrices. Maecenas ut facilisis erat.
                    Donec quis malesuada lacus. Sed iaculis dui vestibulum porta pretium. Cras tincidunt justo vel
                    tellus ornare, non aliquam dolor rutrum. Suspendisse interdum neque arcu, sit amet mattis urna
                    tincidunt vel. Integer fringilla nec tellus in scelerisque. Nulla placerat facilisis felis, non
                    posuere lorem ultrices eu. Quisque accumsan fermentum purus vel aliquam. Fusce id libero vitae dui
                    pretium posuere euismod vel odio.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="show-more-container">
                <input id="ch-3" type="checkbox">
                <label id=label-show-3 for="ch-3"></label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span class="offer-price-tag">
                    500
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image: Normal view]

[image: Mobile view - spoiled one]

Comment: The demo doesn't seem to show the problem. Please revise so it does. We can't debug images. Is all that scripting necessary for this question? See [ask] and simplify as far as possible.

Comment: Edit your question to include a [mcve] please

Comment: Ok, I believe now it's cleaner. Please, let me know if there is still need for revision.

Comment: The problem we are having here is that when we test your snippet, it looks fine.  I simulate mobile screen size and everything goes smoothly to one column.  Could you test in another browser yourself to rule out a cache issue?  Or send a link to a live example where you are seeing the error?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the whole environment where website lives but I can ensure it only behaves wrong in wordpress and every ammendment ends up with fiasco - still throwing out the content of the box.